# Mpeg-dash code integration with videoJs player

Tags: video-streaming, video.js, adaptive-bitrate, mpeg-dash

I am using videoJs player to play videos , i need to know is there any support for mpeg-dash in videoJS ? ..I referred this link http://msdnrss.thecoderblogs.com/2014/01/mpeg-dash-tutorial-embedding-an-adaptive-streaming-video-within-your-html5-application-2/ to play mpeg-dash video .

In code

```
 videojs(this.get('element')); //here this.get('element') refers to video object
 var url= .mpd manifest file
 var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
 var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
 player.startup();
 player.attachView(this.get('element')); //
 player.attachSource(url);
```

Now mpeg-dash video will play but videoJS and Dash is not linked with each other ,
so i need to know , how i can bind dash to videoJs player ?

Comment: I adopted different way, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484539/dynamic-smil-file-with-videojs-and-wowza-for-hls

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this link: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/752 which says that you'll need to specify a type attribute on the video element (specifically type="application/dash+xml"). Also I'm not sure if Safari supports DASH yet (or ever will) but  the latest versions of Chrome/Firefox should.

Comment: Safari 8 on Yosemite now supports MSE and therefore can play MPEG-DASH.

Answer (score 1):

please refer [videojs-contrib-dash](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-dash)

```
  const options = {
         "preload": "auto",
         "width":"600 px",
         hls: {
           withCredentials: true
         },
         plugins: {
           videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
             // default: 'high',
             dynamicLabel: true
           }
         },
         html5: {
          nativeCaptions: false,
          dash: {
            setLimitBitrateByPortal: false,
            // setMaxAllowedBitrateFor: ['video', 2000]
          }
        }
      };
         videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.swf"
         this.video = videojs(this.videoElement.nativeElement,options);
         this.video.src([
             {
               type: "application/dash+xml",
               src: "your url",
               }
           ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may switch to [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) or [bitdash](http://www.dash-player.com) for MPEG-DASH playback. As far as I know there is also a video.js wrapper for dash.js.